# Toggling classes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a popup element here:

```
<div id="contactme" class="closed"> 
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle_contactme">Close</a>       
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle_contactme">Open</a>
```

I have made two classes **`.open`** and **`.closed`** each with the css:

```
.closed{
  visibility: hidden;
}
.open{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Using jQuery I have found errors with opening and closing the popup, and i'm unsure whether it is the CSS or just incorrect jQuery.

Here is the function when you click on the open or close button:

```
function toggle_contactme(){

   if ($("#contactme").hasClass("closed")) {

       $("#contactme").removeClass("closed").addClass("open");

   }else if ( $("#contactme").hasClass("open") ){

       $("#contactme").removeClass("open").addClass("closed");

   };

}
```

When running this code, it opens the popup but fails to close it, any help would be appreciated!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXCEv/

Comment: Why not just use `.toggleClass()`? And `onclick="toggle_contactme"` should be `onclick="toggle_contactme"()`.

Comment: This looks like it would work, what's the error?

Comment: It should work, but for some reason it is opening and then not closing when i click the close link

Comment: ahh a silly little mistake, the close link had `();` missing from the end of the function being called!

Comment: you have a semicolon closing your `else if`, btw.

Comment: @ethorn10 erm i can't see one?

Comment: @SAMTHEMAN999 the line just prior to the final closing `}` is `};` - that `;` is unnecessary. It looks like you've already figured out what the issue was though.

Answer (score 2):

To fully hide and show elements you should not use `visibility: hidden;`. Sure, it hides the element, but it still there occupying the space. You want to use `display: none;` to fully hide the element. jQuery has functions for this called [.hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) which will set/unset the `display` value of the element.

In this case, since you wish to toggle between the two states, check out the [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function that does exactly that.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXCEv/1/

**Edit:** For animated versions, check out [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [.fadeToogle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/).

Working example (animated): http://jsfiddle.net/ZXCEv/3/

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="hidden">Close</a>
<a href="#">Open</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {

    $('a').click(function() {

        // $('a').toggle(); // Unanimated
        $('a').fadeToggle(); // Animated

    });

});
```

Comment: so could I just do `$("#contactme").hide();` ?

Comment: Just updated with at working JSFiddle, check it out!

Comment: the only reason I use `visibility: hidden;` is so I can add transition duration to it, unless you know how you an add animation to something that is changing its `display`.

Comment: Sure, check out [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [.fadeToogle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/). That should be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is also to change the `Open / Close` buttons text
I'd suggest you do do it in a more dynamic way:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/hucapo/6/edit)**

```
<div data-togglable="contactme" data-hidden> 
    <a href="#" data-toggler="contactme"></a>
    <p>lorem ipsum.....</p>
</div>
<a href="#" data-toggler="contactme"></a>
```

- in the demo just remove `data-hidden` and see what happens.
- Yes, you don't need to write your buttons *Open/Close* text. jQuery will handle it for you

CSS:

```
[data-hidden]{ display:none; }
```

jQ:

```
// 1. Set the needed text for the element's related buttons
// Iterate all your elements with "data-togglable" 
// and find out the needed text for that element's related buttons
$('[data-togglable]').each(function(){      
    var dataTarget = $(this).data('togglable');
    var $targetBtn = $('[data-toggler='+ dataTarget +']');
    var togglerTxt = typeof $(this).data('hidden') !== 'undefined' ? "Open" : "Close";
  $('[data-toggler='+ dataTarget +']').text( togglerTxt );
});

// 2. Assign a click handler to your buttons
// and change state/text
$('[data-toggler]').click(function(event){      
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var dataTarget = $(this).data('toggler');
    var $targetEle = $('[data-togglable='+ dataTarget +']');
    var togglerTxt = $targetEle.is(':hidden') ? "Close" : "Open";
    $targetEle.slideToggle();
    $('[data-toggler='+ dataTarget +']').text( togglerTxt );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
onclick="toggle_contactme"
```

To:

```
onclick="toggle_contactme()" // missing () after the function name
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXCEv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

just change your html to this

```
<div id="contactme" class="closed"> 
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle_contactme()">Close</a>       
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle_contactme()">Open</a>
```